# Error: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, r.java-file, setcontentview

I'm new on Android and I have a problem, the function `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` shows error. I have the `activity_main.xml` under the `resource/layout` folder.

**error log:**

```
12-30 13:58:42.891 15586-15586/edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme/edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                         at edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                         at edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                         at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:190)
                                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:250)
                                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172)
                                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                         at edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02004d a=-1 r=0x7f02004d}
                                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
                                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                        at android.view.Lay
12-30 13:58:42.891 394-523/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity edu.upc.idi.nebot.jonathan.recipeme/.MainActivity
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):

Answer (score 1):

If you're using android Studio 1.5 make sure you didn't add your drawables to to (v21) folder, i don't know why the system doesn't read .png or .jpg files from this folder

Comment: for this this was not taking images from v24 folder thanks